# Import JSON via ajax and looping through

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

obviously I am newbie. I am trying to load a json file via ajax, then loop through that array to populate a graph using a cytoscape.js package (another question for another day). 
Before I begin my loop to create new nodes and edges, I am trying to test my loop to verify the output. However, nothing it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Springy.js image node demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="springy.js"></script>
<script src="springyui.js"></script>
<script src="bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    


      // get exported json from cytoscape desktop via ajax
  var graphP = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://rawgit.com/theresajbecker/CompBio/master/TokyosmallTest/Tokyosmall2.json', // tokyo-railways.json
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  });  
    console.log(graphP);
    var node = graphP.nodes;
    //var employee2 = elements.edges;

    for ( var i in node) {
        var id = nodes[i].id;
        var station_name = nodes[i].station_name;
        console.log(id);
        console.log(station_name);
    }

</script>

</body></html>
```

This should produce the output of node id and station name but it's not. The console.(log) produces: Object {readyState: 1}
What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks

Comment: You are using `$.ajax` incorrectly. Please read its documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or maybe better, a tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: `graphP` is a XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object not your json response.

Answer (score 2):

It is because [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
 is async.

Try:

```
  // get exported json from cytoscape desktop via ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://rawgit.com/theresajbecker/CompBio/master/TokyosmallTest/Tokyosmall2.json', // tokyo-railways.json
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (graphP) {  
    console.log(graphP);
    var node = graphP.nodes;
    //var employee2 = elements.edges;

    for ( var i in node) {
        var id = nodes[i].id;
        var station_name = nodes[i].station_name;
        console.log(id);
        console.log(station_name);
    }
  });
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8f8q7fwp/)

Comment: Yes. Thank you!  Adding the done solved that as well as removed a dependency from another piece I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/noL55gbu/)***

The main problem is that `$.ajax` isn't going to return the json. It is going to inject it into a success callback function. So what you need to do is move your expected code below which uses the "value" from `$.ajax` to be inside of the success function.

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://rawgit.com/theresajbecker/CompBio/master/TokyosmallTest/Tokyosmall2.json', // tokyo-railways.json
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(graphP){
  console.log(graphP);
  //the structure of the json is slightly different than your mappings
  //for example
  var firstNodeId = graphP.elements.nodes[0].data.id;//is the first id
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to                                                                           for (var i = 0; i < graphP.elements.nodes.length; i++) {  
        var node = graphP.elements.nodes[i].data.id;
        console.log(graphP.elements.nodes[i].data.id);

Comment: @leafgirl - Yes that would iterate the set of nodes and access their data ids.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax queries are asynchronous, you must wait for it to complete :
`var query = $.ajax({url: url', // tokyo-railways.json
                         type: 'GET',
                         dataType: 'json'
     })
     .done(function( graphP ) {
        //Your code here
        console.log(graphP);
     });`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$.getJSON( "https://rawgit.com/theresajbecker/CompBio/master/TokyosmallTest/Tokyosmall2.json", function( data ) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.elements.nodes.length; i++) {  
    var node = data.elements.nodes[i];
    console.log(node.data.id);
  }
});
```

For further reading:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/